# countif: count all occurences of value in a column that match value from another cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I have the following data on sheet 2

```
Name        
Mark Jacob
James Smith
```

On sheet 1  I have a name column in column a and i want to count the total number of times the name in column a appears in the name column on sheet 2. Like so:

Name               Total
Mark Jacob           1
Harry Potter         0

I am using the following countif function:

```
=COUNTIF('Sheet2'!K:K,"*"&"A2"&"*")
```

For some reason however my value always returns 0

However if I replace my Cell reference A2 from my function with 'Mark' this gives me a result of 1. Why is this?

Please can someone show me where I am going wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet2!K:K,"*"&A2&"*")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion however this still isn't working

Comment: For some reason if I delete the value from my cell on sheet 2 and retype it in exactly as was, it works but not sure what could be causing this, theres definitely no spaces or anything

Comment: There must be something funky with the data. I've tested this here several times and it never fails to work.

Answer (score 1):

You are treating A2 as a literal, so you need to remove the quotes from it.  An added benefit, would be if you are using the variable, then you can also copy and paste it to a range.  Also, double check the formulas for each cell to ensure it is mapping to the correct column.  Eg.:

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!$D:$D,"*"&F5&"*")
```